# What is the right way to create multiple wx.AcceleratorEntry() entries and bind functions to them? wxPython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

currently I'm working on my wxPython final High school project and I am facing another problem
I would like to bind keystroke combination entries (for example CTRL+S...) to my functions, but I can not achieve the result that would fulfill my expectations.

I've tried this, but the keystrokes were not bound.

```
accelnum = 2

        accelerators = [wx.AcceleratorEntry() for x in range(accelnum)]

        accelerators[0].Set(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('S'), 'save')
        accelerators[1].Set(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('E'), 'export')


        accel=wx.AcceleratorTable(accelerators)
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel)


def save(self, event):
        # some code...

def export(self, event):
        # some other code...
```

I also tried to set ID to the same ID like i set to my toolbar tools but it says
that 'id' is not valid argument here.

Thank you very much for for all the advices. R

***EDIT***

For all wondering what could be wrong, I also used wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK to detect "DEL" key. When I was rewriting my class second time, I forgot to add EVT_CHAR_HOOK and it worked. Until I added that EVT_CHAR_HOOK back. That means You can not use it simultaneously. So what I did next:

```
ID_SAVE = wx.NewIdRef()
ID_EXPORT = wx.NewIdRef()
ID_DELETE = wx.NewIdRef()
accelerators = [wx.AcceleratorEntry() for x in range(3)]
accelerators[0].Set(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('S'), ID_SAVE)
accelerators[1].Set(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('E'), ID_EXPORT)
accelerators[2].Set(wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, wx.WXK_DELETE, ID_DELETE)
```

to assign also my delete button and it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robin's answer, as always, does indeed work.
You may wish to check, exactly how you are implementing it.
Try something like this:

```
import wx

ID_SAVE = wx.NewIdRef()
ID_EXPORT = wx.NewIdRef()
accelerators = [wx.AcceleratorEntry() for x in range(2)]
accelerators[0].Set(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('S'), ID_SAVE)
accelerators[1].Set(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('E'), ID_EXPORT)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", size=(360,100)):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title, size)
        accel=wx.AcceleratorTable(accelerators)
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, id=ID_SAVE)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExport, id=ID_EXPORT)
        self.Show()

    def OnSave(self, event):
        print("Save")
        event.Skip()

    def OnExport(self, event):
        print("Export")
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None,title="An Accelerator Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Well.. Even after rewriting whole class (forgot to add panel) I was not able to make it work. Your program works very well so probably I have made some mistake. I'll try to fix it. Anyways. Thank you

Comment: Second rewriting did the job. I can finnaly access those functions. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

See: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.AcceleratorEntry.html#wx.AcceleratorEntry.Set

The 3rd parameter to `Set` is should be the ID to be used when the event is created and sent. So you'll want to do it something like this instead:

```
    ID_SAVE = wx.NewIdRef()
    accelerators[0].Set(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('S'), ID_SAVE)
```

When that key is pressed then an `EVT_MENU` event is sent, so you'll also need to bind a handler for it, like this:

```
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.save, id=ID_SAVE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already explain the 'how to'. Maybe this example can make coding somewhat easier for new readers.

As you can read in the other answers creating an accelerator needs 3 steps: 1) create an id, 2) create an accelerator and 3) bind to EVT_MENU. It took me some time to get it working myself.

So after 'getting the right way' I created a way to make it easier for me, **"the easier way"**, when using a lot of accelerators by defining them in one place.

```
        self._accelerators = {

            wx.NewIdRef(): {'text': 'Previous Page (PageUp)',
                            'flags': wx.ACCEL_NORMAL,
                            'keyCode': wx.WXK_PAGEUP,
                            'handler': self.on_previous},

            wx.NewIdRef(): {'text': 'Next Page (PageDown)',
                            'flags': wx.ACCEL_NORMAL,
                            'keyCode': wx.WXK_PAGEDOWN,
                            'handler': self.on_next},

            wx.NewIdRef(): {'text': 'Select All (Ctrl+A)',
                            'flags': wx.ACCEL_CTRL,
                            'keyCode': ord('a'),
                            'handler': self.on_select_all},
        }
```

And then let python do the boring stuff.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def _create_accelerators(self):

    entries = []
    for event_id, accelerator in self._accelerators.items():

        # create the accelerator ---------------------------------------------
        entry = wx.AcceleratorEntry(accelerator['flags'], accelerator['keyCode'], event_id)
        entries.append(entry)

        # bind handler to EVT_MENU ----------------------------------------
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, accelerator['handler'], id=event_id)

    accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable(entries)
    self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)
```

A complete working example.

```
import wx


class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Accelerator Test", size=(500, 500))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        # define the accelerators ---------------------------------------------
        self._accelerators = {

            wx.NewIdRef(): {'text': 'Previous Page (PageUp)',
                            'flags': wx.ACCEL_NORMAL,
                            'keyCode': wx.WXK_PAGEUP,
                            'handler': self.on_previous},

            wx.NewIdRef(): {'text': 'Next Page (PageDown)',
                            'flags': wx.ACCEL_NORMAL,
                            'keyCode': wx.WXK_PAGEDOWN,
                            'handler': self.on_next},

            wx.NewIdRef(): {'text': 'Select All (Ctrl+A)',
                            'flags': wx.ACCEL_CTRL,
                            'keyCode': ord('a'),
                            'handler': self.on_select_all},

        }

        # create the accelerators ---------------------------
        self._create_accelerators()

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def _create_accelerators(self):

        entries = []
        for event_id, accelerator in self._accelerators.items():

            # create the accelerator ---------------------------------------------
            entry = wx.AcceleratorEntry(accelerator['flags'], accelerator['keyCode'], event_id)
            entries.append(entry)

            # bind handler to EVT_MENU ----------------------------------------
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, accelerator['handler'], id=event_id)

        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable(entries)
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_previous(self, event):

        print(f"You pressed {self._accelerators[event.GetId()]['text']}")

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_next(self, event):

        print(f"You pressed {self._accelerators[event.GetId()]['text']}")

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_select_all(self, event):

        print(f"You pressed {self._accelerators[event.GetId()]['text']}")


# ===================================================================================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Some output.

```
You pressed Next Page (PageDown)
You pressed Previous Page (PageUp)
You pressed Select All (Ctrl+A)
```